# Is it possible to rewrite protected method in helpers?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

Is it possible to rewrite protected method like this in helpers?

```
class Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_Filter extends Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_Abstract
{
 ...
    protected function _applyShortcodes(&$content, $object, $context) {
```

Comment: No, it breaks oop concept then.

Comment: Iam not sure this works but once have a try by looking at this [link1](http://magefox.com/blog/how-to-override-a-magento-core-block-class.html) and [link2](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-block-controller-model-helper-override/)advice to maintain a backup.

Comment: oh sorry.protected method can accessed by inherited class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a subclass of Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_Filter, yes - the subclass can override a protected method http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: that was i thought. thx